# How to create tabs as block in shopify (with Alpine JS)

Tags: tabs, shopify, alpine.js

This is my default code, but i need Tab name to be as a block so i can add and remove from Dashboard of Shopify.

```
<div class="tab-wrapper" x-data="{ activeTab:  0 }">
  <div class="flex">
    <label
      @click="activeTab = 0"
      class="tab-control"
      :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 0 }"
    >Tab 1</label>
    <label
      @click="activeTab = 1"
      class="tab-control"
      :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 1 }"
    >Tab 2</label>
    <label
      @click="activeTab = 2"
      class="tab-control"
      :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 2 }"
    >Tab 3</label>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-panel" :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 0 }" x-show.transition.in.opacity.duration.600="activeTab === 0">
    <p>This is the example content of the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-panel" :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 1 }" x-show.transition.in.opacity.duration.600="activeTab === 1">
    <p>The second tab’s example content.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-panel" :class="{ 'active': activeTab === 2 }" x-show.transition.in.opacity.duration.600="activeTab === 2">
    <p>The content of the third and final tab in this set.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then after this content should be with swiper slide

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `collapsible-content.liquid` built in the Shopify section modify it, and convert it into tabs as per your need.

You need to change its markup with the markup you need to put.
change its config as per your requirements and add the correct CSS.

### Copy `collapsible-content.liquid` file, rename it and edit it

[image]

### Check its preview

[image]

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thanks but i need something with Alpine JS without using default section code

Comment: hmm then i guess you need to write custom code